# IIS rewrite to compare Cookie Value against database list

Tags: iis, cookies, url-rewriting

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to create a URL rewrite rule in IIS that will compare the value of a cookie against a list in a database (or another form of dynamically update-able list)? If so, how?

I can make it check for a specific cookie value or one that matches a pattern but I really need to compare it against a list of authorised IDs.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, this is not possible.

What you could try is to write your own **URL Rewrite custom provider**, in it you may be able to access a database.

See [Developing a custom rewrite provider for url rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module)

It may be easier to include such logic in your own application.

Comment: Writing a custom provider looks promising. Normally I would handle this in the application however the idea of this system to handle the amount of traffic being allowed through to the application so want it to be handled before it hits the application.